# Trying to create a dynamic partial page in MVC3 from telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, view, partial

I have an MVC3 web app where the current view I have is using a model type of

```
IList<Application.Models.dbTable>
```

The reason I use the IList<> is so the telerik grid on the page can understand the output.
my goal is to have a partial page on the right that uses a model of application.model.dbTable which is dynamic so when you select an item on the telerik grid it changes the content of the partial page based on the index of the item selected on the telerik grid.
Currently im getting an error saying that the partial view requires a model of type application.model.dbTable.  It seems to be inheriting the model from the view that the partial is nested in.  Also, how can I pass a default value to this partial view as it requires an index value to display data?
Any help would be great, I couldnt find anything too specific to this situation when I did my research.
Code below:

Index.cshtml:

```
 @model IList<application.Models.dbTable>

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

        @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
            .Name("emailList")
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
        )

        @Html.Partial("DetailedLinkInfo");
```

DetailedLinkInfo.cshtml:
     @model application.Models.dbTable

```
 <fieldset>
     <legend>email</legend>

     <div class="display-label">sender</div>
     <div class="display-field">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sender)
     </div>

     <div class="display-label">subject</div>
     <div class="display-field">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.subject)
     </div>

     <div class="display-label">priority</div>
     <div class="display-field">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.priority)
     </div>
 </fieldset>
 <p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ID }) |
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </p>
```

Controller:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Application.Models;

```
namespace Application.Controllers
{
    public class applicationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /email/


        dbRepository er = new dbRepository();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = er.findAll();

            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DetailedLinkInfo(int id)
        {
            if (id==null)
            {
                id = 1;
            }
            var details = er.findOne(id);
            return PartialView(details);
        } 

    }
}
```